# didEnterRegion never gets called in ios

Tags: ios, notifications, core-location

Not sure what I'm doing wrong.  I want a local notification to be triggered, telling the user that he's near by a particular object. My code is as following:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters;
self.locationManager.delegate = self;
[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

CLLocationDistance radius = 1000.00;


CLLocationCoordinate2D location2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(_location.coordinate.latitude, _location.coordinate.longitude);

CLCircularRegion *region = [[CLCircularRegion alloc] initWithCenter:location2D
                                                             radius:radius
                                                         identifier:@"theRegion"];


[self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:region];
}



- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{
    NSLog(@"GeoFence: didEnterRegion");

    UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    notification.alertBody = @"You entered a region";
    notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:notification];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are already in the region, you will not get notified that you entered a region, because the state hasn't changed.

On iOS 7 and later, you can use `-[CLLocationManager requestStateForRegion:]` to request the current state for a region as you start to monitor it. `-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didDetermineState:(CLRegionState)state forRegion:(CLRegion *)region` on your CLLocationManagerDelegate.

If you need to support iOS 6, you can do this manually by checking if the region contains the device's current coordinate, via `-[CLRegion containsCoordinate:]`

Comment: `-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didDetermineState:(CLRegionState)state forRegion:(CLRegion *)region` works great, however I only want a notification for when the user enters an area, and not exit. How do i do this?

Comment: Check out the properties that are available for you on CLCircularRegion.