# Why is didEnterRegion delegate called intermittently?

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager, ibeacon

This is a follow up to question to [Why is didEnterRegion not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43780765/why-is-my-didenterregion-delegate-not-called)

Now the didEnterRegion call is made "sometimes" but not always, if I delete the app, install the app and have the beacon off and then start the beacon it works most of the time, my debugs show me all the correct info but its just not reliable.

I KNOW 100% the beacon is ok and broadcasting because I have a beacon scanner next to the setup and I see it directly go on and off on my command

here is my full code, nothing left out

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    // Initialize location manager and set ourselves as the delegate
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status {
    NSLog(@"authstate changed was hit wit status %d", status);

    if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways) {
        // Create a NSUUID with the same UUID as the broadcasting beacon
        NSUUID *uuid = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:@"39876A4B-43B2-4BE8-9A9C-41BAE913D56A"];

        // Setup a new region with that UUID and same identifier as the broadcasting beacon
        _myBeaconRegion= [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:uuid
                                                            identifier:@"me.netwizards.office"];

        [_locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:_myBeaconRegion];
        NSLog(@"location Manager started to monitor regions: %@", self.locationManager.monitoredRegions);
    } else {
        [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
        NSLog(@"requesting again");
    }
}


- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Error : %@",error);
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager monitoringDidFailForRegion:(CLRegion *)region withError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Region monitoring failed with error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager*)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion*)region
{
    NSLog(@"Did Enter Region");
    [self.locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:self.myBeaconRegion];
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager*)manager didExitRegion:(CLRegion*)region
{
    [self.locationManager stopRangingBeaconsInRegion:self.myBeaconRegion];
    self.viewControllerStoreLbl.text = @"No Store Detected";
    self.viewControllerOpeningTimesLbl.text = @"No Store Detected";
    NSLog(@"Did Exit Region");
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager*)manager
       didRangeBeacons:(NSArray*)beacons
              inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion*)region
{
    // Beacon found!
    self.viewControllerStoreLbl.text = @"Matts Test Store";
    self.viewControllerOpeningTimesLbl.text = @"Open 9 AM to 9 PM";

    CLBeacon *foundBeacon = [beacons firstObject];

    // You can retrieve the beacon data from its properties
    NSString *uuid = foundBeacon.proximityUUID.UUIDString;
    NSString *major = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", foundBeacon.major];
    NSString *minor = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", foundBeacon.minor];

    NSLog(@"Beacon Data: UUID: %@, major: %@, minor: %@", uuid, major, minor);
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@end
```

Here is the debug showing me that region monitoring starts just fine and that the location manager Auth delegate is called ok and works as expected

```
2017-05-05 17:05:45.102718 NW SelfCheckout[225:4033] authstate changed was hit wit status 0
2017-05-05 17:05:45.104175 NW SelfCheckout[225:4033] requesting again
2017-05-05 17:05:47.314500 NW SelfCheckout[225:4033] authstate changed was hit wit status 3
2017-05-05 17:05:47.327998 NW SelfCheckout[225:4033] location Manager started to monitor regions: {(
    CLBeaconRegion (identifier:'me.netwizards.office', uuid:39876A4B-43B2-4BE8-9A9C-41BAE913D56A, major:(null), minor:(null))
)}
```

but after that nothing happens, I can wait for hours, turn beacon on and off remove beacon from range etc nothing makes it work, rebooting device still don't help

What can possibly be wrong?

Comment: see this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/23375780/3901620

Comment: ok so I added the call to determineState of the region, but do I need to do anything in the delegate? or the cLl itself is enough to trigger the functionally?

Comment: yes if you want to any operation related to region you can do here.

Comment: This seems to work but I need to do some more testing, the delegate works as expected so I added in case its inside I start doing my things and thats ok for now, stay tunes

Comment: ok @Matt Douhan